# Weird vertical lines when I color in the model

Tags: modeling

[image]

-As the title says I get these weird vertical lines on my model when I put a texture on it/color it in, mostly when I use planes to make my models. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's because you are using UV texture coordinates (default for image textures) which means you have to unwrap your mesh after extruding the planes for the textures to display properly. The alternative is to add a texture coordinate node to your graph, connect the "generated" coordinate to your image texture and change the projection from "flat" to "box". For proper (controllable) results, I would highly recommend the UV unwrapping route, however.

Comment: If you are brand new to the UV unwrap/texture mapping process, here's a good resource (it's long but in-depth). It's definitely something you want to familiarize yourself with up-front, because the way you plan to texture map things may also impact how you go about your modelling process. Link is here - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/